# Redis pub sub and socket io

Tags: redis, socket.io

I am actually new to redis . So what is the purpose of redis pub sub when you have socket io ?  So lets say for a chat app, socket io is used for users to send message from client to server then the server will take the message and emit it to the user based on its socket id. So what is redis pub sub used for in this instance ?

Lets say I have a client, can redis emit events to it ?

I am kinda confused.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis pub sub is used when you have more than 1 server or process to which the clients are connected.

If server/process A receives a message that needs to be sent to client B who is connected to server/process B - how would you do that with just socket io? This is where redis pub sub comes in. Server A does a pub that server B receives which then forwards it on to client B

Comment: I see, I understand now. So you use redis to segregrate events to other server instances  right ?

Comment: Segregate means to divide. Not segregate but to communicate